# Nginx prevent hotlinking from one domain

Tags: nginx

I'm having a terrible time doing what I thought would be a simple task. We need to prevent hotlinking to one directory and one script from one domain. Here are my nginx rules

```
  location /gallery/files/6/7/5/ {
    if ($http_referer ~ ^(http://www.badsite.com|http://badsite.com)) {
      rewrite ^ http://www.oursite.com/hotlink.jpg;
    }
  }

  location /gallery/displayimage.php {
    if ($http_referer ~ ^(http://www.badsite.com|http://badsite.com)) {
      rewrite ^ http://www.oursite.com/hotlink.jpg;
    }
  }
```

If it's not self explanatory, there are a bunch of .jpg files in oursite.com/gallery/files/6/7/5 and there is also a proxy script at oursite.com/gallery/displayimage.php that outputs a JPG image. We need to block access to both of these locations, but ONLY when the referrer is badsite.com

I'm admittedly not an expert on nginx configuration, but I thought the above blocks would work for our needs. Instead, the hotlinks are still working without issue on badsite.com - Requests are not being sent to hotlink.jpg

Comment: Perhaps the [`valid_referers`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRefererModule#valid_referers) module is of help for you? You could then specify something like `valid_referers *.badsite.com badsite.com` and then use the inverse of `$invalid_refer`. I haven't tested this, but it might be of help.

Comment: That looks like it would work, but I'd really like to know/understand why my code isn't working as written so that I can better understand nginx.

Comment: Could it be the protocol? `https://badsite.com/` is not matched by the above rule. Note that your rule will also match `https://www-badsite.com` (since `.` has a special meaning in regular expressions). Note: if you would like to perform an HTTP redirect, you could also use `return http://www.oursite.com/hotlink.jpg`. For an internal redirect, drop the scheme and host name.

Comment: Not the protocol. Good catch on escaping the . I will try that next.